# Using psql, how to test if I am using streaming, hot_standby or warm replication?

Tags: postgresql

I am on Postgresql version 10.4

How can I know using `psql` that if the server I am using is in a `streaming`, `hot_standby`, or `warm` replication mode?

I really have no idea what these replications do other than `hot_standby` is only a read-only server, and it and `warm` use WAL archives and `streaming` archive does not use WAL.

And also, are these the only modes of replication or are there some other modes of replication too?

If possible, explain like I am five because this is my second day of using Postgresql.

Comment: Have you tried `SHOW ALL`?

Answer (score 0):

Streaming **does** use WAL.  It obtains the WAL by streaming it, rather than (or in addition to) shipping entire WAL files at a time.  Also, the choice of hot_standby versus warm standby is independent of the choice of streaming versus log shipping.  It would be unusual to use hot_standby without also using streaming in the modern age, but it is perfectly possible to do so.

On the master, you can see if there are active receivers of WAL streaming by looking at `pg_stat_replication`.  If there are no entries, than no one is currently streaming wal.

For log shipping, you can look in `archive_mode`.  If that is turned off (or if it turned on but `archive_command` is some dummy command), then no one can be receiving the shipped log files as they are not being archived in the first place.  If it is on and archive_command is sensible, then someone might be doing something with the archived logs files.  The master server has no direct way of knowing whether someone is or is not.

In either case, the master doesn't generally know what they are doing with WAL.  They could be using the WAL for warm standby, they could be using it for hot standby, they could be storing it cold for future use, they could be just tossing it in the trash. Some of the fields in `pg_stat_replication` can give you some clues about what is going on, but who knows, the client programs might be lying.  And for log shipping, there is no way to know anything.